# Android Studio - HttpUrlConnection & BufferedReader doesn't read everything?

Tags: android, inputstream, httpurlconnection, bufferedreader

So when running this code on a smaller page it runs fine. But when I run it on a larger page such as Stackoverflow or anything else it doesn't get the complete source code in the String results. Is there something I am not considering or doing wrong guys? Thanks!

Example: for StackOverflow it stops at line 35 of the source code only a few characters in, instead of the 3000+ lines of code.

Last line from Log:

> StackExchange.using("gp

My code:

```
protected void runItNow(View v){
    Log.i("INSIDE: ", "runItNow");

    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
    String result;
    try {
        result = downloadTask.execute("http://www.stackoverflow.com/").get();


    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection;

        try{

            url = new URL(params[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(250000);

            int data;
            char[] buffer = new char[4096];
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            while ((data = reader.read(buffer)) != -1){
                builder.append(buffer, 0, data);
            }

            String results = builder.toString();
            Log.i("Results: ", results);


            in.close();
            reader.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
            return results;


        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: `).get();` Dont use the .get(). Bad programming! Use onPostExecute() of the  AsyncTask to handle the result.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That is how I normally do it but this was the way the StackSkill lessons went. Lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you checking the output only with `Log.i("Results: ", results);`? Logcat is probably cutting the rest of the characters. Try writing it to a file and check its contents.

Comment: Dang it, I'm so silly. I don't know why I didnt think about that. Thanks!